# Best iOS UI object choice for a scrollable sequence of 'pages'

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview, uiscrollview

I am completely new to iOS development (I'm a .NET dev).  I am experimenting with MonoTouch, but if I hit problems will switch to Objective-C.  I need a steer on how to architect my UI.  I am looking to develop an iPad app that will have several 'pages' of questions that a user will navigate through horizontally. Only one page will be shown at a time. Each page will typically have one question, but it may have many checkboxes or radio buttons for the answers and the user may need to scroll certain pages vertically to see all the possible answer options.  The user will use a sweeping left/right gesture to navigate between the pages.  If they gesture up/down then the app should scroll the current page up and down.

Ideally if they flick the screen enthusiastically the horizontal animated scrolling should scroll them through several pages.  On arriving at a page the page should 'snap' into view.

So, in a nutshell, which UI object(s) should I use to achieve this?  The questions will be built dynamically from database-stored JSON definitions.  Once they reach the end of the questionnaire it will upload the captured data to a web service and reset the questionnaire.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a UIScrollView, or a UIPageControl.  There is an excellent tutorial here: http://www.accella.net/objective-c-multiple-pages-in-a-uiscrollview/ which perfectly answers your question.